# Dialogflow V2 API call Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, rest, dialogflow-es

I have a question for you guys. In Dialogflow API V1 I've used the following code to connect my chatbot widget to Dialogflow API V1:

```
function send(query) {
  var text = query;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: baseUrl + "query?v=20180101",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: "somerandomthing" }),
    success: function(data) {
      setResponse(data);
    }
  });
}
```

This is not working anymore, and I can't get it to work when I try to connect it to V2 - even when I read the specified docs for V2 -. Do you guys have an example for me how I can fix it?
I've tried different solutions, but none of them work for me:
eg.: [Dialogflow V2 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783524/dialogflow-v2-api)

Maybe I can try to call the REST API?
I don't feel comfortable using Node.js, because of the fact that I don't know how to do programming in that language.
Thanks for your help.